# Spring Batch: How to pass data from StepExecution to JobExecution without persisting it (that is, without using ExecutionContext)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a JobExecutionListener.afterJob() implementation which prints some info obtained from all previous step executions:

JobExecutionListener.beforeJob():

```
jobExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("key", "");
```

step1: StepExecutionListener.beforeStep():

```
ExecutionContext context = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
context.putString("key", context.getString("key") + "Hello");
```

step2: StepExecutionListener.beforeStep():

```
ExecutionContext context = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
context.putString("key", context.getString("key") + " World!");
```

JobExecutionListener.afterJob():

```
System.out.println(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("key"));
// results in "Hello World!"
```

But when executing such a job this data would be persisted (e.g., in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` table). How to avoid this?

Comment: Well, the data is persisted because that's the behaviour of your jobRepository. You could change the jobRepository to the non-persistent version but this is not recommended since then you wouldn't be able to store anything persistently. Did you try in the JobExecutionListener.afterJob() jobExecution.getExecutionContext.remove("key")? I'm not sure, but maybe this could remove the data. If this also doesn't work I'm afraid you can't use the contexts, but you will have to define a singleton bean with a map for this data, shared between your steps..

Answer (score 1):

Use an external bean holding data you want to pass between step; this external bean is not persisted and you need to wire into your SB artifacts or listeners.

Comment: But how can I adjust that bean's scope so it will be automatically instantiated once per job execution (keeping in mind that there may be multiple jobs running concurrently)? Explicitly including it as a part of every job configuration is not the best idea.

Comment: Use a singleton bean holding a set of your non-serilizable data beans,binding to current job thread or job's id. The idea is to use an external bean instead of an `ExecutionContext` (and modify this idea on you needs)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci : Could you please tell me how to do this ? I could'nt understand ` you need to wire into your SB artifacts or listeners`. I need to achieve the same functionality. I tried it like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300601/spring-batch-autowire-bean-in-writer-not-working-by-configuring-it-via-job-java) and not working. Please help

Comment: Into your listener or other artifacts (reader, writer, etc) create a setter to inject a singleton bean used to pass data across steps. This bean will not be saved into database so it will be lost if you stop and resume a job