# Spring batch autowire bean in writer not working by configuring it via job java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have to autowire an object to my writer class of spring batch job. This has to be specific for job ( job scope ) I am trying to configure it my spring batch job java configuration calss and use it by autowire fashion from my writer class. But this seems to be not working and I always gets this bean as null from my writer class. What am I doing wrong.

My Job configuration class snippet :

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class ProducerBatchJobConfigurer {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

    @Bean
    @Scope("job")
    ErrorNotificationBean notificationBean(@Value("#{jobParameters[s3FilePath]}") String s3FileName,@Value("#{jobParameters[jobId]}") String jobId){
        return new ErrorNotificationBean(jobId,s3FileName);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("job")
    public ZipMultiResourceItemReader reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fileName]}") String fileName, @Value("#{jobParameters[s3SourceFolderPrefix]}") String s3SourceFolderPrefix, @Value("#{jobParameters[timeStamp]}") long timeStamp, com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.service.ConfigurationService confService,ErrorNotificationBean notificationBean) {
        CustomFlatFileItemReader faltFileReader = new CustomFlatFileItemReader();
        ZipMultiResourceItemReader zipReader = new ZipMultiResourceItemReader();
        Resource[] resArray = new Resource[1];
        System.out.println(notificationBean.getS3FileLocation());
        resArray[0] = new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName));
        zipReader.setArchives(resArray);
        DefaultLineMapper<ProducerMessage> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<ProducerMessage>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
        CSVFieldMapper csvFieldMapper = new CSVFieldMapper(fileName, s3SourceFolderPrefix, timeStamp, confService);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(csvFieldMapper);
        faltFileReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        zipReader.setDelegate(faltFileReader);
        return zipReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties
    @Scope("job")
    public ItemStreamWriter<ProducerMessage> writer(ErrorNotificationBean notificationBean) {
        return new RdsWriter();
    }
```

And I am trying to get the bean `notificationBean` by autowiring from my writer class as below.

```
public class RdsWriter extends AbstractItemStreamItemWriter<ProducerMessage> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rdsJdbcTemplate")
    JdbcTemplate rdsJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    ErrorNotificationBean notificationBean ;
```

ErrorNotification is plain java object which has some fields.

```
package com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Bean for Error Notifications.
 */
@Component
public class ErrorNotificationBean {
    private String subject ;
    private int rowsSkipped;
    private String feedName;
    private String s3FileLocation;
    private String uniqueId;

    public ErrorNotificationBean(String uniqueId, String s3FileLocation) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.s3FileLocation = s3FileLocation;
    }
    public ErrorNotificationBean(){

    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getRowsSkipped() {
        return rowsSkipped;
    }

    public void setRowsSkipped(int rowsSkipped) {
        this.rowsSkipped = rowsSkipped;
    }

    public String getFeedName() {
        return feedName;
    }

    public void setFeedName(String feedName) {
        this.feedName = feedName;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getS3FileLocation() {
        return s3FileLocation;
    }

    public void setS3FileLocation(String s3FileLocation) {
        this.s3FileLocation = s3FileLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784984/spring-batch-how-to-pass-jobparameters-to-a-custom-bean?rq=1 It may be related

Comment: @TheresaForster: Thanks for the reply. I don't think so . I have specified the scope properly. The thing in my case is that the configuration function `notificationBean()` never gets called.

Comment: is the autowire going to pass in the parameters needed for creation? have you got those before the autowire hits?

Comment: @TheresaForster : I did'nt get you. Are you asking if the notficationBean parameter passed in the method `reader` working ? It is not working I tried printing this inside reader function it is not working. It should be taken the bean configured with function `notificationBean` right ?

Comment: new ErrornotificationBean() doesnt set anything up, you need to make it call the other stuff correctly, have you confirmed which one is being called on autowire, the () or the one with the parameters?  try making the () private and see if it works.